# Is service entrance cable rated for outdoor use without rigid conduit?

Tags: electrical, meter

I need to replace the service line for 200A service and the current line is just fastened to the exterior wall with straps. It does terminate at a service head but the rest is unprotected, including where it enters the home.  I'm rather uncomfortable with leaving this cable unprotected, but it would also be very difficult to install rigid conduit given the odd angles it would need to make.

What is required? and what is best practice when the path from the service head to the meter is nowhere near a straight line?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/v5iz4u21r0yayee/IMG_0307.jpg?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/4ktyvcck8t8thkc/IMG_0305.jpg?dl=0

Don't judge.  It's a very ugly house.  Hence the renovation.  Yes, all the garbage is gone.  I took these before we brought in a demolition team. As you can see there is a service head limply hanging there which sloppily wraps around the house to the basement with 2ga wire.  Obviously I need to replace it with 4/0 for 200A, but I'd like to make it a little more presentable for the inspector.

Comment: Recommendations for routing conduit would really need a photo of the location for a decent answer. The category of SE cable is broad, sunlight resistant jacketed SE cable can be exposed, unjacketed is generally needed for inside of conduit.

Comment: Understood.  I’ll get one tomorrow and append to the post.

Comment: The deal where there are 3 hooks for the 3 wires is "on the outs", now they want a weatherhead, which by design sits at the top of a conduit.  It's not that big a deal to move the weatherhead, the power company has to make that attachment anyway. Bonus points if it means the service drop shorter, but forcing it to be longer will force the PoCo to replace the service drop, which they probably won't do otherwise until your demand data shows you need it.

Comment: If the SE cable is below 8’ it would require conduit, it sounds like yours is overhead but a better description would be needed, I have not used hooks for 20+ years, if you are updating to a larger feed you will probably need to bring it up to current code, the only time I know of a reconnect without an inspection is for weather and tree limbs taking out a service. They will connect without an inspection in several states I have worked.